# How to modify state of button from trigger in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracleforms

I have to modify state of button (hide it) in Oracle Forms (10g -- I am new to Forms and I not sure how to recognize the version).

Unfortunately I cannot modify the form itself.

I can add my own code only to procedures called by `PRE-FORM`, `POST-FORM` and `WHEN-NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE` (something like that) triggers.

However:
 1. `PRE-FORM` is called too early (form modifies button after this trigger).
 1. `POST-FORM` is called when child form is closed (it's OK, but doesn't handle all cases).

`WHEN-NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE` seems good but I failed trying access button from procedure called from trigger.

I tried to use `name_in('datablock.element')` to access form elements but I have no idea how to modify the state of element outside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit hard to say when I don't know where your custom code is located. Usually you are hiding items by setting the Visible property to False using forms builtin Set_Item_Property. This should work both from the forms itself and any attached pll library. The syntax is:

```
Set_Item_Property(<block_name.item_name>, VISIBLE, PROPERTY_FALSE);
```

Comment: `Set_Item_Property()` was what I tried before but it seemed it fails. Today I tried again I found the real source of problem. Thanks!